# Process substitution inside a subshell to set a variable

Tags: bash, variable, subshell, process-substitution

I'm trying to run a script remotely and use its standard output to populate a variable.  I'm doing this to avoid temporary files.

Here's the pattern I'm trying:

```
var=$(bash <(curl -fsSkL http://remote/file.sh))
echo "var=${var}"
```

I'm testing this pattern without `curl` using `cat`:

```
var=$(bash <(cat ./local/file.sh))
echo "var=${var}"
```

This *should* be the same as far as syntax is concerned.  `./local/file.sh` contains `echo hello`, so I would expect `var` to contain the value `hello`, but alas, executing the above results in the following:

```
test.sh: command substitution: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
test.sh: command substitution: line 4: `bash <(cat ./local/file.sh)'
var=
```

How can I accomplish my goal without using temporary files?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Those are the errors you get when trying to perform a process substitution in `bash` when the shell is running in POSIX mode. The `bash` shell does not support process substitutions in POSIX mode.

`bash` will run in POSIX mode when either

1. `set -o posix` has been used, or
2. the shell is being invoked as `sh`.

My hunch is that you have a script, `test.sh`, that you are running with `sh test.sh` or that has a `#!/bin/sh` hashbang line, and that your `sh` happens to be `bash`.  Another possibility is that the script does *not* have `#!`-line at all, and it is being invoked by `bash`-as-`sh` in some other way.

Instead, see to that your `test.sh` script is being invoked by `bash`.

Example:

```
$ cat script.sh
echo hello
```

```
$ cat test.sh
var=$(bash <( cat script.sh ))
printf 'var="%s"\n' "$var"
```

```
$ bash -o posix test.sh
test.sh: command substitution: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
test.sh: command substitution: line 2: `bash <( cat script.sh ))'
var=""
```

```
$ bash test.sh
var="hello"
```

---

If you want to do this in a portable way in your `test.sh` script using POSIX `sh`:

```
var=$( cat script.sh | bash )
printf 'var="%s"\n' "$var"
```

This would have the effect of the `bash` process reading the output of `cat` on its standard input, which is *not quite* the same as your process substitution variant (which leaves standard input alone). This matters if the script that the internal `bash` shell executes does any form of reading of data from its standard input.

If you need to leave the `bash` shell's standard input alone (because you need to read from it), you may possibly assume that `mktemp` is available and use

```
var=$( tmpfile=$(mktemp); cat script.sh >"$tmpfile" && bash "$tmpfile"; rm -f "$tmpfile" )
printf 'var="%s"\n' "$var"
```

Where `cat script.sh` is understood to later be replaced by your `curl` command.

If you're comfortable with juggling file descriptors, you could also make file descriptor 3 a copy of the standard input descriptor before calling the `bash` shell, and then let the fetched script read from that:

```
var=$( exec 3<&0; cat script.sh | bash )
printf 'var="%s"\n' "$var"
```

The `script.sh` script would then use `read -u 3` to read from the *original* standard input stream, or `utility <&3` to redirect that input stream into another utility.

Comment: Yep, I was invoking as `sh` – I didn't realize POSIX didn't support these features. Thanks! As a short follow-up, is there a way to ensure `bash`-as-`sh` (if invoked incorrectly) will not run in POSIX mode? In other words, what is the converse of `set -o posix`?

Comment: @SeanAllred Since `sh` does not need to be `bash` and indeed, `sh` is _often_ not `bash`, you should rather make sure that your scripts are executed by `bash`.  A simple way to do this is to make the script executable and add `#!/bin/bash` as the first line in the script (adapt that to the correct path to the `bash` executable on your system).  Then run it without specifying an explicit interpreter.

Comment: Yes I can ensure that my tools use bash, via shebang or otherwise, but I'm concerned that those using the script I'm making will not invoke it correctly. Is there no converse to option `posix`? (Working under the assumption now that there's no means by which to accomplish my goal – without temp files – with only POSIX features.)

Comment: @SeanAllred If you are sharing your script with others, it _extra_ important to have a `#!/bin/bash` line! The `sh` shell on many Linux machines is `dash`, and that shell would not understand process substitutions however hard you tried. On my machine (OpenBSD), `sh` is `pdksh`, and that also can't be made to run process substitutions.  What you are asking is the equivalent to how to make someone invoke a Python script with the correct Python interpreter even when they run it with a Ruby interpreter. If the user picks the wrong interpreter, then the documentation was not good enough.

Comment: Well of course there will be a shebang line :-) but fair enough – I guess there's a limit to how much you can protect others from themselves. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Sean At least POSIX features should be enough to check whether the shell is bash and quit gracefully otherwise.